# Extracting specific data from an RData file

Tags: r, rdata

I ask to be excused for my ignorance of R which I have been learning for the past one month. Specifically I have downloaded xxx_adm-_RData files (xxx for the country and - being 0, 1 or 2) for a number of countries of interest. My real interest are just the long/lat coordinates of each country, which I can use to overlay on analyses of climate fields like rainfall, temperature, etc. For the past two weeks I have been going through SO posts on how I can access a country's coordinates in an RData file and use them with other data, without any success. My attempts to get google maps or readGR() or readBin() after a download have not been successful. I wonder whether what am asking for is feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after putting the rdata file in your working directory, do something like

```
load("C:/Users/1_adm.RData", ex <- new.env())
ls.str(ex)
```

The rdata loads variable into your workspace so that command will show you what the variable names are, so you can then use them.

I don't have the file you're talking about so I can't tell you how to access the specific fields you need.

**edit**

Based on your comment:
Ok so the object you load is an object of type SpatialPolygonsDataFrame, and that has a Slot/property called Polygons, with objects of type Polygon. Those polygons I assume are the lat lng coordinates around the country. Accessing the coordinates should look something like

```
ps <- gadm@polygons[1]
```

then something like

```
ps@coords
```

Comment: Thanks @AwokeKnowing, I actually did a load(), and here is what I get:> ls.str(ne)
gadm : Loading required package: sp
Formal class 'SpatialPolygonsDataFrame' [package "sp"] with 5 slots. Let me emphasize that it is not only knowing what is there, but how to get hold of and use it. I have for example map a map of a country with unemployment rate in zambia (from ZMB_adm2.RData), but it is not the data in RData am interested in but how I can get hold of and use longitude and latitude in RData

Comment: again, nobody can help you because they cannot see the data.  post a list of sample data and someone might help you extract what you need and tell you how to plot it,etc.

Comment: Right now I just cannot figure where I downloaded the data (I have been working on this daily all day for two weeks now), but I downloaded several countries as ZMB_adm0.Rdata (Zambia), TZA_adm0.RData, etc. As soon as I get the link i will post it. I suppose I cannot attach the file to this post.

Comment: again, if you load the file, and list out the head()  we can see what's in there. you can paste those first 10 rows here.

Comment: After loading, when I do ls() I get gadm, them head(gadm) gives: > head(gadm)
Loading required package: sp
An object of class "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"
Slot "data":
  PID
1 187

Slot "polygons":
[[1]]
An object of class "Polygons"
Slot "Polygons":
[[1]]
An object of class "Polygon"
Slot "labpt":
[1] 29.923502 -2.000434

Slot "area":
[1] 2.053383

Slot "hole":
[1] FALSE

Slot "ringDir":
[1] 1

Slot "coords":
            [,1]      [,2]
   [1,] 30.44742 -1.045227
   [2,] 30.44778 -1.045345
   [3,] 30.44804 -1.045128
   [4,] 30.44833 -1.045328
   [5,] 30.44835 -1.045942
   and more ....

Comment: ok so the object you load is an object of type SpatialPolygonsDataFrame, and that has a Slot/property called Polygons, with objects of type Polygon.  those polygons I assume are the lat lng coordinates around the country.   accessing the coordinates should look something like  ps <- gadm@polygons[1]   then something like ps@coords  should list the coordinates.  I can't really test unless you provide a link.  it seems like you need be looking for the source of your data, and some instructions, though.

Comment: With your assistance, I think I have made some progress. This is the site where I got the data http://www.gadm.org/country. This is what I tried: load("RWA_adm0.RData and I get "gadm SpatialPolygonsDataFrame", I can also do lon <- gadm[,1] and lat <- gadm in the hope of extracting longitude only and latitude only into x and y respectively. Both x and y are listed as "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame" and when I do print(lon) I still get longitudes and latitudes listed. My problem is: how do I use these coordinates as an overlay on a map?

Comment: with your hints and the code provided by Henrik I have been able to solve my problem.The three lines which enabled me to prepare the map for overlay are: load("C:/R_Progs/Country_Maps/RWA_adm0.RData"); rwa <- get("gadm"); rwa2 <- fortify(rwa) then the plotting function provided by Henrik, thanks, works.

Comment: great, sorry I couldn't spend more time on it. glad you got it working. I'd appreciate an upvote if you found this helpful.

Comment: sorry i did not learn much on procedures of SO, I have been looking where I can give an upvote, could you please guide me how to.

Comment: you just click the ^ right where it says 1 Answer at this post.  If you also want to mark this as the best answer, put your mouse over the check mark space under the  upvote and downvote arrows, and click it to mark the green checkmark