# Removing variables loaded from an RData file in R

Tags: r

Suppose I saved two variables:

```
x <- rnorm(5)
y <- letters[1:10]
save(x, y, file = "MySavedList.RData")
rm(x,y)
```

Later, I want to load this saved file (`MySavedList.RData`) and after using these variables I want to remove only the variables that are loaded from `MySavedList.RData`. All of the remaining variables in the environment should be intact. 
Something like this:

```
load(file = "MySavedList.RData")
...
rm("Variables loaded from MySavedList.RData")
```

I don't want to load these files into a new environment ([like this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19575237/2275286)), or create a variable that holds the variable names when I first save the variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would something like this work for you?

```
theloadedobjects <- load(file = "MySavedList.RData")
...
rm(list=c(theloadedobjects, "theloadedobjects"))
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Well, `rm(list = c(theloadedobjects, "theloadedobjects"))` to be more precise. Thank you a lot.

Comment: Ah, yes, good point ! I will edit my answer to include this as well.